# What's the lookup cost in prefix tree and why?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, prefix-tree

Given an prefix tree and a key. What's the cost of looking up the key in the tree?

I read in a paper that it's O(1). As far as I know it's O(LogM) where M is the length of the key. I couldn't find an answer to this as why it's O(1) but one mentioned that the point could be that if we ignore scanning the key then it would be O(1). Can someone explain to me graphically (by making a tree and traversing) how it is O(1) if we ignore scanning the key?

Answer (score 0):

The cost of looking up a key inside of a Trie is not `O(1)`.

The total time is `O(l)` where `l` is the minimum of the length of the word you are trying to match, or the depth of the tree. Notice that many people write this as `O(log n)` where n is the total elements in the tree.

You start at the root of the tree.  You only need to traverse the 1 node that will match your current word. You continue this traversal until you have matched the word, or the word is not within the tree. As you only search 1 child per node, it is `O(l)`.